# mysql is not accepting decimal in the right format

Tags: c#, mysql, decimal

When I am sending decimal value from C# for example : 5.54
When I am executing query I can see that my variables are represented as 5,54

Anyone have an idea how to achieve to get DOT and not COMMA?

Here is my code:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString()))
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                {  
                    cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT Test (lat, long) VALUES ({0},{1})",
                                                   OSGconv.deciLat, OSGconv.deciLon);
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with the other advice. As to the other question regarding comma or dot, it depends on the CurrentCulture. To get the right format you would have to use a ToString, [providing Culture.InvariantCulture as the second parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dx8etks.aspx). This will use the dot for decimal separator.

But, I insist, the other answer is very good advice: use DbParameters. And I add: pass the value as held in C#, not converting it to string. It will be correctly handled by the ADO.NET provider. I.e. if you have to pass a `float` variable, do pass it without converting to `string`, but as is, as a `float` value.

Comment: okay sure I will use parameters. But this is just for testing. And where do I put that Culture parameter?

Answer (score 4):

> Anyone have an idea how to achieve to get DOT and not COMMA?

Don't embed the values into your SQL directly to start with. Use parameterized SQL instead. See the documentation for [`MySqlCommand.Parameters`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-parameters) for an example. You should *always* use parameterized queries:

- They separate code from data
- They prevent SQL injection attacks (not an issue for these numbers, but consider strings...)
- They prevent conversion issues like this

There's a more general point here: don't perform any more conversions than you have to. Every time you convert data from one form to another, you risk losing data or worse. If you can keep your data in the most appropriate representation for as long as possible, you'll minimize the problems.

Comment: Can you give me some example please? You mean something like stored procedures?

Comment: @denonth: No, I mean parameterized SQL, where you specify placeholders in the SQL, and then specify the *values* separately.

Comment: @denonth: I've added a link to the MySQL documentation which should help you. Searches should give you plenty more examples on the web.

Comment: thank you for your answer. is it possible to give me the example based on my database request? I think the link is broken.